# Laravel - Relation not push in the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I trying to save the record with relation by using push() it work well for the first save but I click save it in the second time it doesn't push the relation Laravel 5.5.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Session::has('_leave-generation')) {
        $ids = $request->input('id');
        $data = $request->input('data');
        $leaveGenerate = Session::get('_leave-generation');
        $leaveGenerate->fill($data);
        $this->leaveGenerationItemService->setStatus($ids, $leaveGenerate);
        if($leaveGenerate->push())
        {
            $this->leaveBalanceService->generateLeaveEntitle();
        }
    }
}

public function setStatus($ids, LeaveGeneration $leaveGeneration)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++) {
        $id = $ids[$i];
        $item = $leaveGeneration->items->find($id);
        $item->status = 'P';
        $item = $leaveGeneration->items->find($id)->fill($item->toArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you define the relationship?

Comment: I define that:
leaveGeneration hasMany Items and Item belongsTo leaveGeneration.